# How to calculate with cummin() until condition is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to calculate the minimum value until `cond` column is true

Then recalculate the minimum value starting from the next row where the `cond` column is true

The obtained result is assigned to the `expected` column

input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A=[16,12,21,15,18,19,13,16,10,50]
cond=[False,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'cond':cond})
df
```

the expected table

```
    A   cond    expected
0   16  FALSE   
1   12  FALSE   
2   21  TRUE    12
3   15  FALSE   12
4   18  FALSE   12
5   19  TRUE    15
6   13  FALSE   15
7   16  FALSE   15
8   10  TRUE    10
9   50  FALSE   10
```

Index 5 calculates the minimum value from index 3 to index 5

Index 8 calculates the minimum value from index 6 to index 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the reverse `cumsum` on `cond` to identify blocks of rows, then group the column `A` by these blocks and `transform` with `min` to calculate minimum value per block then mask the values and use `ffill` to propagate last min values in forward direction

```
b = df['cond'][::-1].cumsum()
df['result'] = df['A'].groupby(b).transform('min').mask(~df['cond']).ffill()
```

---

```
    A   cond  result
0  16  False     NaN
1  12  False     NaN
2  21   True    12.0
3  15  False    12.0
4  18  False    12.0
5  19   True    15.0
6  13  False    15.0
7  16  False    15.0
8  10   True    10.0
9  50  False    10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with pandas, but I got it to make a python array with the expected values.

```
A=[16,12,21,15,18,19,13,16,10,50]
cond=[False,False,True,False,False,True,False,False,True,False]

output = []
low = max(A) + 1
lowPrint = 0

for i, j in zip(A, cond):
    if i < low: low = i
    if j:
        lowPrint = low
        low = max(A) + 1
    output.append(lowPrint)
```

As I said, I don't know much about pandas but I assume you can use this to get the values then do as you want with them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired column by getting the min `ms` in each range and doing a forward fill.

```
arr = np.array([16, 12, 21, 15, 18, 19, 13, 16, 10, 50])
c = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]).astype(bool)

i = np.flatnonzero(c)
splits = np.split(arr, i+1)[:-1]
ms = [s.min() for s in splits]

arr = arr.astype(float)
arr[~c] = np.nan
arr[c] = ms

df = pd.DataFrame(arr).ffill(); df
```

output:

```
      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2  12.0
3  12.0
4  12.0
5  15.0
6  15.0
7  15.0
8  10.0
9  10.0
```